# Why won't my custom function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When creating my own jQuery method, why does this work:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.test = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).html("Hi there");
        });
    } 
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(){
        $(this).test().css("color", "orange");
    });
});
```

But this does not?

```
(function($){
    $.fn.test = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).html("Hi there");
        });
    } 
    $("body").click(function(){
        $(this).test().css("color", "orange");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried replacing `$` with `jQuery` but it still doesn't work. It only seems to work within a separate doc.ready function, can anyone explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because the second one runs before the document is ready? Is that in a script included in the header? I think you'll find that your custom function does work, but the `"body"` selector is returning an empty jQuery object because the body isn't parsed yet.

Comment: Where is this script when it runs? In the `<head>` or near the bottom of the `<body>`?

Answer (score 2):

Your second snippet isn't working as expected because

```
(function($) {...})(jQuery)
```

is run **before** the document is ready.

By wrapping your

```
$('body').click(function () {...})
```

inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {...})
```

you are telling jQuery to run

```
$('body').click(function () {...})
```

after the page has loaded.

---

**What you (probably) want to do instead:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.test = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).html("Hi there");
        });
    }
    $("body").click(function() {
        $(this).test().css("color", "orange");
    });
});
```

This will run both the

```
$.fn.test = function() {...}
```

and the

```
$("body").click(function() {...}
```

*after* the document is ready (which is basically when the page is fully loaded, it's a bit different, but it would not be constructive to expound upon that here).